# How to add private composer repository for dev only

Tags: php, composer-php

Currently I'm using a private repository with a composer package like this:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/ns/a-repo.git"
  }
],
"require-dev": {
  "ns/a-repo": "@dev"
},
```

The package is only required as dev-dependency. If I run the command `composer install --no-dev`, composer will still require the authentication for the private repository, even though the package will not be installed.

Is there a way to tag the defined repository as dev only to avoid the authentication?

Comment: Do you have `composer.lock` in your project, while you run `composer install --no-dev`?

Comment: @rob006 Yes - there is a `composer.lock` and it contains an entry for `ns/a-repo` in `packages-dev`. I get the same result (composer asking for authentication) if I run the install with and without the lock file.